# ajax: how to identify which api request has failed inside the then after all requests have completed

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have two ajax calls i.e.

```
   var url1Response, url2Response;

   var ajax1 = $.ajax({
                    url: Url1,
                    success: function (response) {
                        url1Response= response;
                    }

                });

   var ajax2 = $.ajax({
                    url: Url2,
                    success: function (response) {
                        url2Response= response;
                    }
                });

       $.when(ajax1, ajax2).done(function (response1, response2) {

       });

       $.when(ajax1, ajax2).then(function (response1, response2) {

       });
```

Once ajax1, ajax2 are completed:

1. ajax1 success, ajax2 success: works fine, gets inside done/then.
2. ajax1 success, ajax2 fail: gets inside then but NOT inside done.
3. ajax1 fail, ajax2 fail: gets inside then but NOT inside done.

The problem is how do I identify which API has failed inside the then statement? And, I want success/fail inside then when both have got the response back. There's no use if I get success/failure of any of these before another request has completed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.when(ajax1, ajax2).done(function (response1, response2) {

}).fail(function(response1, response2) {
    // here you can check which response failed
});
```

Comment: Not working, response1 is giving api error, i.e. if both fails-response1 error has ajax1 error, if only ajax1 fails-response1 error has ajax1 error, if only ajax2 fails-response1 error has ajax2 error. The response2 in all above cases has string value "errors"